# how to convert Console.WriteLine in to RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, textbox, console

how to convert `Console.WriteLine` to `RichTextBox`?

I was wondering if anyone knew and I do not know (for something I put the question) ... I searched and found nothing so I want to know if any of you can help me

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/9hutzo.png]

Answer (score 2):

You can use AppendText as below

```
//Console.WriteLine("Hello");

richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("{0}{1}", "Hello", Environment.NewLine));
```

### EDIT

As per your comments you want to write text form windows form to a console application

Add class called Win32 to your project like below

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SoTest
{
    public class Win32
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Allocates a new console for current process.
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean AllocConsole();

        /// <summary>
        /// Frees the console.
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean FreeConsole();
    }
}
```

You have to do few changes to windows form application like below

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Win32.AllocConsole();  //Allocates a new console for current process.
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // on button click we write text to console 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text); // write RTB text to console 
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)  // add form closing event 
    {
        Win32.FreeConsole(); // Free the console.
    }
```

Done!

[image]

[Refere This blog Post for more information](http://www.debugrelease.com/2009/09/01/output-to-console-in-windows-forms-application/)

Comment: I do not know if l modified my post or wrong but is backwards D =, I want the contents of a RichTextBox be a Console.WriteLine

Comment: @user that comments does not makes things any clearer. I cannot think of a way to interpret your question other than the answer here. You may need to add an example to the question to help us understand.